# What are the abilities of the "Special Infected" in Left 2 Die?

Tags: starcraft-2, mods

Blizzard's Left 2 Die custom map, a mashup of Left 4 Dead and their own Outbreak campaign mission, starts out with familiar zerg units (from the campaign, if not from multiplayer) assaulting your base, but even during the first night, you will be attacked by "special infected" (so named in the SC2mapfile).

These are:

- Hunterling
- Choker
- Spotter
- Stank

As a formerly avid Left 4 Dead player, I notice the named similarity between these 4 zerg units and Valve's original special infected.

However, due to the random matchmaking nature of the custom games I tried, I have yet to survive the first night or encounter anything other than the Hunterling (which jumps up cliffs? Maybe something else?).

What are the traits and special abilities of these 4 units? Bonus points if you include pictures of the 4 special infested!

Comment: The reason you haven't seen then is because the game usually runs in Casual difficulty. If you create and host your own game, you can change the difficulty. On higher difficulties, you will encounter all of the different types of infected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's actually 5 units. I pulled the screenshots from [sc2armory.com](http://sc2armory.com/media/screenshots/Left-2-Die-_-Spotter/676) and [gamereplays.org](http://www.gamereplays.org/starcraft2/portals.php?show=news&news_id=737312).

**Choker**

Attempts to pull units with its ranged tentacles. Attacks ground units.

[image: Choker attempting to drag a seiged tank.]

**Hunterling**

Leaps walls. Attacks ground units.

[image: A pair of hunterlings.]

**Kaboomer**

Spits acid to attack and explodes when it dies. Attacks ground units.

[image: Banelings, banelings, banelings, oh!]

**Spotter**

Flies. Locks down structures by covering them in slime. Attacks ground and air units.

[image: You did NOT just shoot that green stuff at me!]

**Stank**

Headbutts units. Attacks ground units, damages multiple units simultaneously.

[image: That zerg is stank.]