# What's a "Stank" and how do I find one?

Tags: starcraft-2

As I was browsing through the SC2 portraits I have seen a strange one:

[image: stank portrait]

What is a Stank, and how, more importantly, where do I complete this task?

Comment: When I first seen this question I misread "Stank" as, well, something else...

Comment: Related: [What are the abilities of the “Special Infected” in Left 2 Die?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/16004/3107). It will give you more information about what a Stank is, how you encounter it, and what it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that is one of the achievements of the Left2Die map from Blizzard. If I remember it right the stank is a big, hulky, boss thingy. (One of the models they created for that map).

[How to kill it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErmwkrUIYQU)

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's very similar to Ultralisk. Left 2 Die is a custom game (mod by Blizzard).